# any OCR online or SDK recommendations

Tags: ocr

Need to call some OCR function to extract characters from images. Wondering if anyone have good recommendations? Not necessarily to be open source and free.

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: http://www.abbyy.com/ocr-sdk-windows/

Comment: @AndrejAdamenko, looks like it could only call very limited number of images?

Comment: This is off-topic. Please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @LinMa, I did not work with this API, but the end-user SW they sell is good.

Comment: @AndrejAdamenko, what do you mean end-user SW? The SDK you referred?

Comment: My understanding was that the SDK is the API you may try. I meant the product for OCR is good: http://www.abbyy.com/finereader/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- When it come to OCR(optical character recognition) Tesseract is consider a better choice.
  https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract
- There is another library called microblink ocr. Code is available for ios, android and phone gap. Its accuracy is very good.
  https://microblink.com/ocr

Comment: thanks and do you know if microblink supports Chinese characters?

Comment: Not sure exactly about support for Chinese characters. Language support is defined in testdata. I just test it with english character and result was great. thanks

Comment: Tesseract support chinese simplified and traditional.  A full list of langs can be found [here](http://tesseract.patagames.com/langs/)

Answer (score 1):

I have used [GOCR](http://jocr.sourceforge.net/) a while ago, it's a command line tool, you can integrate it in your script if you are working server-side. I was satisfied with the result, it did a great job.

Comment: do you know if it support Chinese? Thanks.